# Access position parameters in multi-command inline alias/command

Tags: bash, position, command-line-arguments, alias, argument-passing

I'm trying to create an alias for a command that renames a folder and then tar-zips it:

```
alias txz='of=$1; nf=$of$(date -I); mv $of $nf; tar cJvf $nf.txz $nf --remove-files'
```

call with

```
txz test_folder
```

I get errors

```
mv: missing destination file operand after ‘2014-05-14’
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
tar: 2014-05-14: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
test_folder/
test_folder/1
test_folder/2
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Because of multiple commands. If there is only one command (no `;`), `$1` works.

Is there any way to resolve it?

ps: here is the command to create the test folder:

```
mkdir test_folder; touch test_folder/1 test_folder/2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to make it a function like this as aliases don't have support for positional parameters like `$1, $2` etc:

```
txz() {
   of="$1"
   nf="$of"$(date -I)
   mv "$of" "$nf"
   tar cJvf "$nf.txz" "$nf" --remove-files
}
```

Or to make in one line:

```
txz() { of="$1"; nf="$of"$(date -I); mv "$of" "$nf"; tar cJvf "$nf.txz" "$nf" --remove-files; }
```

Comment: Thank you. i'm looking for an inline answer

Comment: This can be made incline also: `txz() {
of="$1";
nf="$of"$(date -I);
mv "$of" "$nf";
tar cJvf "$nf.txz" "$nf" --remove-files;
}`

Comment: @kirill_igum aliases don't support positional parameters.

Comment: Thanks @thatotherguy I should have added that at first place

Comment: I get `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `$1'` error when I copy and paste it

Comment: Try edited code now. @glennjackman: Thanks so much for your edit.

Comment: @anubhava i get the error still: `> txz() { of="$1"; nf="$of"$(date -I); mv "$of" "$nf"; tar cJvf "$nf.txz" "$nf" --remove-files; } 
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `$1'`

Comment: Why do you have `> ` before txz? Did you run `unalias txz` before?